# Как узнать есть ли последовательная часть строки в строке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим есть список списков `sources = [[1,3,3], [1,4,5], [2,5,6], [7,5,7]]` и есть список `target = [1, 4, 8, 5]`,

нужно понять есть ли в списке `sources` список `target`, но сделать это нужно так, что при `target = [1, 4, 8, 5]` выдовало `True` (так как числа полностью соответствуют одному из подлистов `[1, 4, 5]`), но при `target = [1, 6, 5, 7]` выдовало `False` (так как хоть числа `[1, 6, 5, 7]` и находятся в разных подлистах, но не соответствуют полностью не одному из них)

Comment: А `target = [1, 5, 4]` должен выдать `False` соответственно?

Comment: Название вопроса переформулируйте. Задача вообще не про строки. И по тексту тоже непонятно. Каким образом  у вас получается, что все числа 1, 4, 8, 5 содержатся в списке [1, 4, 5]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если порядок чисел в списке не важен, то можно вот так:

```
sources = [[1,3,3], [1,4,5], [2,5,6], [7,5,7]]
target = [1, 4, 8, 5]

for test_list in sources:
    check_list=[]
    for num in test_list:
        if num in target:
            check_list.append(True)
        else:
            check_list.append(False)

    if all(check_list):
        print("Список {} полностью входит в target".format(test_list))
        check = True
    else:
        print("Список {} не входит в target".format(test_list))
        check = False
```